# Make SOQL Case-Insensitive?

Tags: soql, query

I have this query:

```
List<id> accounts1 = [SELECT Id, PersonContactId, PersonEmail, FirstName, LastName, net_Id__pc FROM Account
                         where net_Id__pc = pFederationID]
```

I need the constraint `net_Id__pc = pFederationID` to be case insensitive. For example, if `net_Id__pc = 'jOeDoe'` and `pFederationID = 'joedoe'` then they should be considered equal. How can this be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's case-insensitive by default.

From the `Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference` on [WHERE conditionExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm):

> *comparisonOperator*    Case-insensitive operators that compare values.
>
> **Operator** =
> **Name** Equals
> **Description** Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName equals the specified value in the expression. String comparisons using the equals operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive fields and case-insensitive for all other fields.

Comment: so, if a non case sensitive field is compared against a case sensitive one, what could happen?

Comment: The field configuration is irrelevant. All `SOQL` comparisons are case-insensitive. Full stop.

Comment: Looks like comparison against __mdt (custom metadata record) fields are case-sensitive.

Comment: @wesaw **[That is a bug.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/180997/2995)** The dev team is currently working on a fix.

Comment: yep, but  (WHERE Profile__c LIKE 'System Admin') is still case-insensitive with a bit of performance implication (as a temporary workaround)

Comment: N.B. the case sensitive bug on mdt is defined to be fixed in summer 19 (yea!)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Is there a list of case sensitive fields? I'm thinking fields that are marked as external id / unique... any others?

Comment: Vis-a-vis SOQL that list is *empty*.