# Why are where clause comparison operators case-sensitive when using SOQL to query custom metadata?

Tags: soql, custom-metadata

When using SOQL to query custom metadata records, the comparison in my where clause appears to be case-sensitive.  Example:

MyField__c is a text field that is NOT unique and NOT case sensitive

```
select 
    MyField__c 
from 
    MyCustomMetadataType__mdt
where
    MyField__c = 'testvalue'
```

Results: 0 records

The record is stored as 'TestValue' and the following query finds it:

```
select 
    MyField__c 
from 
    MyCustomMetadataType__mdt
where
    MyField__c = 'TestValue'
```

Results 1 record

This is contrary to SOQL documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm

> Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName equals the
>   specified value in the expression. String comparisons using the equals
>   operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive fields and
>   case-insensitive for all other fields.

Am I missing something or are queries against custom metadata working differently?

**EDIT**
Salesforce has logged this as a known issue and it is under review: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CvkQAE

Comment: I've brought this to the attention of the inventor of Custom Metadata Types. He contributes on here from time to time, so he may be able to shed more light on the issue. Sounds like a bug. I can reproduce the behavior on `cs14` at the very least. You may want to [edit] your post to include which instance you tried it on.

Comment: scheduled for fix in Summer 19 - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CvkQAE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. Please file a case for us.

UPDATE: We're working on a fix.